# How to get dynamically FormFiledWidget values on button click in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to get all the input field values from the listTilewidget on the button click how can I do this?

I have provided the image as well which is here...

we can easily do this with this javascript but is there any way to achieve this type of functionality?

I looked for the solution to this problem on the internet but did not find any solution for that problem.

[image]

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: SupervisorAttendanceServices.getAttendancesDetailsList(
                  widget.attendanceId),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var data = snapshot.data['hamal'];
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(children: [
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 10,
                                    height: 50,
                                  ),
                                  const Icon(FeatherIcons.user),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    data[index]['worker_name'],
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: 150,
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        cursorHeight: 25,
                                        controller: _mainWagesController,
                                        // onChanged: _onChangeHandler,
                                        // initialValue: _mainWagesController.text,
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                            hintText: "Wages",
                                            prefixIcon: Icon(
                                              Icons.wallet,
                                              color: Colors.blue,
                                            )),
                                      )),
                                 
                                ],
                              )
                            ]),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("Something went wrong !"),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: _mainWagesController.text will give you the value of the textfield.

Comment: I want to get every textFormField value in List/Map format. Just like we get in javascript in array formatt sir...@ManishDayma

Comment: here is a thought what you can do is create a list<string> and onchange of every textfield with change the value of its own index on list. like onchange of index 1 will update the value of list[1]= value. that's how you can get all values.

Comment: @ManishDayma Can you please share me some code snippet. Now i understood what you are trying to say...it seems clear solution but please provide some code snippet... And i want data return in map format so that i can understand that which I'd has which value...